# Phrasing a sentence "Do you know any people whom I could combine my efforts with?"

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns, syntax

I'm composing a sentence and I have doubts on whether it's correctly formed.
First I wrote

> 1. "Do you know any people whom I could combine my efforts with?"

than I thought nah, that's not right, and wrote

> 2. "Do you know any people that I could combine my efforts with?"

but that "that" also didn't feel right so I went with

> 3. "Do you know any people I could combine my efforts with?"

What would be the proper way to phrase it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is nearly correct, but it is conventional to put the preposition **with** before **whom**:

> Do you know any people with whom I could combine my efforts?

Here is a [question from EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7932/with-who-vs-with-whom) that justifies the use of **whom**, and incidentally shows where to put the preposition.

Your second option is correct but somewhat unsatisfactory: it is just a way of avoiding the issue of **whom**.

The third is also correct and equally unsatisfactory: it is the same as the second apart from exercising the option to drop the relative pronoun **that**. This is just a personal opinion, but I think that it's OK to exercise this option in spoken English but it's a bit slack for formal, written English.

Note that there is no option to drop the reltive pronoun **who** or **whom**.

Answer (score 1):

Your third sentence

> Do you know any people I could combine my efforts with?

is correct.  Your first sentence is not far off, but could be

> Do you know any people *with* whom I could combine my efforts?

Your sens is correct about the second sentence, since you are asking about a person, "that" is awkward to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it made things clearer for me.